# How to create list of string from generic list using JAVA steam API

Tags: java, java-8

I am learning stream API and wondering how to create simple string list based on an object property from a generic list.
Here is a code:

```
public class Person{
    String name:
    int age;
}

List<Person> plist=myService.getPerson();
List<String> list= plist.stream().map(Person->name).collect(Collectors.toList()); // given syntax error
```

Comment: format the code and you'll see the error

Comment: Of course it gives a syntax error, this is not valid Java. There is no `-->` operator and you're missing at least one dot

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
List<String> list = plist.stream()
    .map(p -> p.name)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I understand this but still getting a syntax error on map(Person::name) "Can't resolve a method name"

Comment: Well if i dont want to create these getter fields then i cant use this stream api ?

Comment: @user565 update `map` method body: `.map(p -> p.name)`

Comment: Of course you can, but I thought you wanted to use `method references`